# Random sample from list of lists

Tags: python, list, random

In python, I have a list of lists, `x`, like so: `[[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`

I have another list, `y`,  like so `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

I need to get 2 random items from `y` that are not together in a list in `x`, so I can switch them around in `x`, with the goal being something like `[[1, 2, 9], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 3]]`. My current method is as follows:

```
done = False
while not done:
    switchers = random.sample(y, 2)
    if indexInCourse(x, switchers[0]) != indexInCourse(course, switchers[1]):
        done = True
```

`indexInCourse` is a function that returns which list an item is in in a list of lists, so for `(x, 1)` it will return `0`. The goal is for `switchers` to be 2 different numbers that are in different lists in the whole, so like `[1, 9]` or `[4, 7]`. My current method works, but is very slow for the large amount of lists I have going through it. Does anyone know of a more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to happen. Please edit your question to make it more specific and include some meaningful examples.

Comment: Is this a genetic or a simulated annealing algorithm for some kind of a timetabling problem? If so, I'd suggest using dictionaries to hold the membership info.

Comment: @ayhen, yeah, it is. I thought about that, but I feel like it would greatly complicate things.

Comment: @pzp, I thought I was clear... I honestly can't tell what I could make better.

Comment: @PaulBuga why not randomly pick two distinct lists from `x` first and then swap a random choice of two elements between them?

Comment: why can't you just first generate two random number from (0,1,2), you can thus pinpoint which of the two sub-list of x you can perform the switch on, then generate another two random number from (0,1,2) **independently, thus can be the same** each represents the index inside the sub-list, then you switch these two...(this is deterministic, so it terminates after three **random**)

Comment: Are all of the elements in `x` also in `y`?

Comment: @pzp, I think y just list indexes(elements inside the sub-lists) of x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not randomly pick two distinct lists from `x` first and *then* swap a random choice of two elements between them?

```
lists = random.sample(x, 2)
# now we swap two random elements between lists[0], lists[1]
```